# Python program rerunning using def functions

Tags: python

The idea is that the program will be used to have many functions. Depending on the user input they'll be sent to a certain `def` within the program with the option to save the data again at the end.

```
score = 0

def Quiz():
    print ("Welcome to the quiz.")
    name = input("Please type your name:")

    print ("Answer the question.")
    Answer == input ("Please enter the answer to 5+6.")

Quiz()

if Answer == "11":
 score = score + 1
 print("Your answer is correct and your score is", score) 
else:
 print ("Your answer is wrong. Your score is", score)

again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))
if again == "yes":
    Quiz()
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

I'm just not sure why it won't run the program and then loop back if the user enters yes.

Any help would be appreciated, I think I'm close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with the code. One of them was mentioned by 6502 in another answer: by having a second Quiz() the program will return to that point after running the Quiz function, so it will automatically drop out after the second go.

A few other things:

- `Answer == input ('  ')` fails because of the `==` which makes Python think it's evaluating equivalence, not assigning the input to Answer
- Answer isn't a global variable, nor is it passed back to the main program, so it will fail when you try to check its value

From your first sentence, I'm not sure what you're trying to do regarding procedures, so either Answer needs to be defined as global, or you need to pass it back from the function, like this:

```
score = 0

def Quiz():
    print ("Welcome to the quiz.")
    name = input("Please type your name:")

    print ("Answer the question.")
    Answer = input ("Please enter the answer to 5+6.")
    return Answer

while True:

    Answer = Quiz()

    if Answer == "11":
     score = score + 1
     print("Your answer is correct and your score is", score)
    else:
     print ("Your answer is wrong. Your score is", score)

    again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))
    if again == "no":
        break
```

but the whole thing could be done more simply without a procedure:

```
score = 0

while True:
    print ("Welcome to the quiz.")
    name = input("Please type your name:")

    print ("Answer the question.")
    Answer = input ("Please enter the answer to 5+6.")

    if Answer == "11":
     score = score + 1
     print("Your answer is correct and your score is", score)
    else:
     print ("Your answer is wrong. Your score is", score)

    again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))
    if again == "no":
        break
```

Finally, neither `Quiz` nor `Answer` should really begin with a capital letter. By PEP8 standards https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-styles function and variable names should begin with lower case letters. It may seem trivial but even in the Stack Overflow question, you can see that Answer has the same colour as the function name, and different to the other variables so it may cause confusion later on.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few bugs. In addition to the previous answer, this is not right either:

```
Answer == input ("Please enter the answer to 5+6.")
```

The program will fail on that. You want to assign an input to the variable Answer, but == are used for comparisons.
Then this:

```
if Answer == "11":
```

the variable Answer is not defined here. You defined it only in the function Quiz.

Regarding your question, you can use a while loop:

```
from random import randint


def quiz():    
    print ("Answer the question.")
    a, b = randint(0, 9), randint(0, 9)
    answer = input("Please enter the answer to {0} + {1}: ".format(a, b))
    return a + b == int(answer)

if __name__=='__main__':          
    again = 'yes'
    score = 0
    print ("Welcome to the quiz.")
    name = input("Please type your name: ")

    while again == 'yes':  # it will go inside at least once         
        if quiz():
            score += 1
            print("Your answer is correct and your score is:", score) 
        else:
            print ("Your answer is wrong. Your score is", score)
        again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))

    print('Your total score is:', score)
```

Answer (score -1):

The second time you call `Quiz()` after asking the answer to the question the program continues, and reaches the end, thus exiting.

What you want to do is a `while` loop instead:

```
score = 0

print ("Welcome to the quiz.")
name = input("Please type your name:")

while True:    
    print ("Answer the question.")
    Answer = input ("Please enter the answer to 5+6.") # only one '='!

    if Answer == "11":
        score = score + 1
        print("Your answer is correct and your score is", score) 
    else:
        print ("Your answer is wrong. Your score is", score)

    again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))
    if again == "no":
        break # this exits the loop
```